# How to explode a dataframe and reduce column values by a certain percentage

Tags: r

I'm learning R and I'm looking for some help in how to approach this problem. I'm looking to generate a dataframe that decreases column values by a certain percentage.

For example:

Take a dataframe:

```
    id
    500
    396
    450
```

I want to manipulate this dataframe to produce the following output - to decrease each of the values by 1.2% four times.

Desired outcome:

```
id  count
500 1
494 2
488.072 3
482.215136  4
476.428554368   5
396 1
391.248 2
386.553024  3
381.914387712   4
377.331415059456    5
450 1
444.6   2
451 3
445.588 4
452 5
```

Comment: I think the last value of `452` is not decreasing compared to 445 in the expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `accumulate` to create the vector of values which resets on each iteration to decrease the new value by 1.2 percentage of the previous value

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
map_dfr(df1$id, ~  
   tibble(id = accumulate(rep(.x, 5),  ~ .x - .y * 0.012 )) %>% 
           mutate(count = row_number()) )
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 15 x 2
#      id count
#   <dbl> <int>
# 1  500      1
# 2  494      2
# 3  488      3
# 4  482      4
# 5  476      5
# 6  396      1
# 7  391.     2
# 8  386.     3
# 9  382.     4
#10  377.     5
#11  450      1
#12  445.     2
#13  439.     3
#14  434.     4
#15  428.     5
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
out <- data.frame(id = numeric(0), count = integer(0))
for(i in seq_along(df1$id)) {
      tmpid <- df1$id[i]
      for(j in 2:5) {
         tmpid[j] <- tmpid[j-1] - tmpid[j-1] * 0.012
      }
   out <- rbind(out, data.frame(id = tmpid, count = 1:5))
 }

out
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(500L, 396L, 450L)), class = "data.frame", 
   row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```